# Strip shortcodes from post text with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I've made a WordPress plugin that uses JS to populate the excerpt textarea of the post edit form with the first few sentences of the post body in the "write post panel". (I know WordPress shows the first 55 words as a default if there's no excerpt - this is what my client wanted.) Unfortunately if there's a shortcode in the post body this appears in my auto-excerpt. For  example

```
[imageshortcode url="http://xxx.co.uk/i/pix/2012/04/12/article-1234237614713-128F6F6E000005DC-482208_636x407.jpg" title="Clock Tower" caption="A clock on top of a train station in Damascus"]
```

Does anybody know some jQuery wheeze I can use to strip out this kind of shortcode from the text I'm taking from the post editor?

Comment: What are the rules for these shortcodes?  It might be as simple as removing square brackets and anything between them.  It would probably work even better if you did this in the PHP of your plugin.  That covers JavaScript-disabled browsers and search engines, too.

Comment: Thanks Surreal - shortcodes area always within square brackets. I don't think I can easily do it with PHP - and this is during the process of editing posts, so SEO and non-JS browsers are not a concern for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case this is useful for anybody else, I ended up using this JS regex to strip out any characters between square brackets from the text, while leaving any text that might've come beween shortcode tags, like [note] ... [/note].

```
var myReg = /\[.+\]/g;
paragraphText = paragraphText.replace(myReg, '');
```

Comment: This regular expression worked for me:  `/\[.*?\]/`

Answer (score 2):

A possible answer can be found [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-remove-short-code-from-post-excerpt). It uses a regular expression.
To remove a particular errant shortcode, use [this.](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/remove-short-code-from-excerpt)
Both of these use PHP, is this what you wanted?

Comment: If this works, my obvious question would be if you used Google before posting here.

Comment: Thanks Srijan, I did Google this.. and no, unfortunately those regexes didn't do the trick for me. I had to do it on the client side.